# MessageSecurityException No signature message parts were specified for messages with the 'http://...' action

Tags: c#, wcf

here is the config file used by both the client and the server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPM_Service" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/PM_Service"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPM_Service"
          contract="IPM_Service" name="WSHttpBinding_IPM_Service">
        <identity>

        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

this is the block of code where I get the error.

```
            ProgrammingMaster_ServiceClient aClient = new ProgrammingMaster_ServiceClient();
            aClient.BeginProgrammingSession(0x01);
            aClient.Close();
```

The second line is where the exception happens at.
`ProgrammingMaster_ServiceClient` is created using the svcutil.exe tool.

this is the code i'm using to start the server.

```
public bool StartService(string aIp)
{
    string lsInstanceId = pFBlock.InstanceId.ToString();
    Uri loBaseAddr = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:808{0}/{1}", lsInstanceId, pFBlock.FBlockName));

    pLocalHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Shadow_ProgrammingMasterService), loBaseAddr);

    Start(aIp);
    return IsHostOpen;
}

private void Start(string aIp)
{
    Shadow_ProgrammingMasterService.SetAPI(this);

    try
    {
        pLocalHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IProgrammingMaster_Service), new WSHttpBinding(), "PM_Service");

        ServiceMetadataBehavior loSmb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        loSmb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        pLocalHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(loSmb);
        try
        {
            pLocalHost.Open();
            IsHostOpen = true;
            pPM_Client = new ProgrammingMasterProxyClient(this, pOutput);
            pPM_Client.IpAddress = aIp;
            this.Subscribe(pPM_Client);
            pOutput.setComment("ProgrammingMasterService initialized");
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            pOutput.setError(ce.Message);
            pLocalHost.Abort();
            IsHostOpen = false;
        }
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ex)
    {
        pOutput.setError(ex.Message);
        pLocalHost.Abort();
        IsHostOpen = false;
        //this.Unsubscribe(pOSTTSClient);
        //pOSTTSClient = null;
    }
}
```

anyone have any ideas of what could be causing this?

Comment: Is your service client proxy fully up to date?

Comment: @ Mr.Disapointment - I thought so but I guess I haven't changed it in a while.  I'll check that.

Comment: @ Mr.Disappointment - That was it.  Thanks. if you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason this occurs in your case is simply that the `WCF` service code itself has been modified, recompiled (and essentially deployed in the debugger) while the client, which has a now outdated service reference, is expecting and depending on something subject to that change and hence conflicts ensue.

Updating the service reference for the client will correct this problem.

To continue, the above is not to say you can't change any code within the service itself once it is referenced by a client (without breaking the client), however, so such a problem suggests substantial changes to parts of the service that the client is depending on, such as the signatures of exposed methods, existing `DataMember` properties of existing  `DataContract` types and the like.

In contrast you can alter the method body of the existing service calls to your heart's content (the client doesn't care *how* the service works, just how to *make* it work); you can also add new members to existing composite `DataContract` types so that new clients may consume your updates readily, preventing `DataType2` type scenarios with redundancy, and so on.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! It is worth noting that if you use reliable messaging, this unhelpful error message can be covered up beneath another one: "The underlying secure session has faulted before the reliable session fully completed. The reliable session was faulted.". This questions' error only showed up in the trace logs.

Comment: What if you're not using service references? What's actually wrong? Note that this message is related to message security, not method signatures. The "signature" in the message is referring to cryptographic signatures.