# wcf client trace svclogfile fault exception

Tags: wcf, soap, trace

I need help figuring out why the Process Action failed
This is my wcf client connecting to an external service. 
My svclog has the following

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-05-15T19:40:53.8202209Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{ee9f3eec-d1b7-45bc-a3a7-1af2ea81a456}" />
<Execution ProcessName="iisexpress" ProcessID="8996" ThreadID="24" />
<Channel />
<Computer>L111</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/27/ROOT-4-130131204474862330</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>No signature message parts were specified for messages with the '' action.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocolFactory.ExtractMessageParts(String action, ScopedMessagePartSpecification scopedParts, Boolean isForSignature)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocolFactory.GetOutgoingSignatureParts(String action)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.ConfigureSendSecurityHeader(Message message, String actor, IList`1 supportingTokens, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.AsymmetricSecurityProtocol.SetUpDelayedSecurityExecution(Message&amp; message, SecurityToken encryptingToken, SecurityToken signingToken, IList`1 supportingTokens, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.AsymmetricSecurityProtocol.SecureOutgoingMessageCore(Message&amp; message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.SecureOutgoingMessage(Message&amp; message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
at ProxyGeneration.MHS.getEligibility(Transaction input)
at ProxyGeneration.MHSClient.getEligibility(Transaction input)
at MYEmedny.mhsclient.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at ASP.mhsclient_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus&amp; notificationStatus)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
</StackTrace>
***<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: No signature message parts were specified for messages with the '' action.</ExceptionString>
</Exception>***
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Is it the message that I am looking at ExceptionString: `No signature message parts were specified for messages with the '' action`

Is this why I am getting a fault exception rejected by policy

Thank you
Sun

Comment: Have you checked this question regarding much the same exception text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033217/messagesecurityexception-no-signature-message-parts-were-specified-for-messages