# WCF No signature message parts were specified for messages with the XXX action

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have imported a WSDL from a different company. I have implemented the WSDL into my own service so the company can call my endpoint.

Locally, my service works. But when I put it on the server and a request is sent; I get the following error:

`No signature message parts were specified for messages with the 'XXX' action.`

The fault that is returned as the following:

```
<s:Fault>
    <faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="">a:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="">The message could not be processed because the action 'XXX' is invalid or unrecognized.</faultstring>
</s:Fault>
```

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033217/messagesecurityexception-no-signature-message-parts-were-specified-for-messages) where the accepted answer says something about the client and service are outdated with eachtother. I have used their WSDL and changed it a bit (some changes were required by the company) but I am unsure if this is the cause (I will do a lot of extra investigation but meanwhile I post this question here to get extra assistance).

The headers in the request ARE signed AFAIK and look completely fine.

Right now I need to do some more digging to expand this question, but I'd love some ideas to investigate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original WSDL from the different company had the correct action URL.

When I imported the WSDL with .NET, the url changed. This meant that while testing locally everything worked because SOAPUI just imported my WSDL and used MY action URL, but when the company tried it, they could get this error because I was not using their action url.

I adjusted the generated WSDL so it uses the correct action url (Adjusting the name of a class and/or adjusting the namespace) and boom, it worked!